# pandas apply function that returns more rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns some of which are lists. I would like to apply a function on each row that essentially expands each row into n rows (n changes for each row) after some data manipulations on the lists.

A simplified version of this can be seen here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0,1],'value':[[0,1,2],[3,4]]}).set_index('id')

def func(x):
    v = np.array(x['value'])
    return pd.Series([v,v**2],index=['value','value_2'])
```

My desired output is:

```
    id  value   value_2
0   0   0   0
1   0   1   1
2   0   2   4
3   1   3   9
4   1   4   16
```

If I apply the function I get an output with the same number of rows as the original dataframe which I then need to reshape:

```
df.apply(func,axis=1)

    value   value_2
id      
0   [0, 1, 2]   [0, 1, 4]
1   [3, 4]  [9, 16]
```

Is there a way to get the desired outcome without needing to reshape after applying the function?

Comment: Do `value` and `value_2` always have the same dimension? if the 3rd row has 7 elements in `value`, does it mean that the 3rd row of `value_2` has 7 elements as well?

Comment: yes. they always have the same dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`unnest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53219045/3483203) then use vectorized operations:

```
u = unnest(df.reset_index(), ['id'], ['value'])
u.assign(value_2=u.value**2)
```

```
   id  value  value_2
0   0      0       0
1   0      1       1
2   0      2       4
3   1      3       9
4   1      4      16
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer is by using `pd.Series` + `stack`

```
df = df.value.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'value'}).set_index('id')
df.apply(func,axis=1)
print(df)
        value   value_2
    id       
    0   0.0     0.0
    0   1.0     1.0
    0   2.0     4.0
    1   3.0     9.0
    1   4.0     16.0
```